# Using variables in callback? scrollview items

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcxjU.png)

remove 2nd item.
but item 1 destroy.

```
class parent
{
    myScroll: scollview;
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        myScroll[i].add(child);
    }

    myScroll[1].removeFunc();
}

class child
{
    static instance : myClass;

    load()
    {
        myClass.instance = this;
    }
    removeFunc()
    {
        this.myDelegate(this.myCallbackFunc);
        //or
        myClass.instance.myDelegate(myClass.instance.myCallbackFunc);
        this.myDelegate(this.myCallbackFunc.bind(this); //same. remove 2nd item. but item 1 destroy. 
    }

    myCallbackFunc()
    {
        this.remove();  // error
        //or
        myClass.instance.remove(); //share... remove 2nd item. but item 1 destroy.
    }
}
```

The myClass in the scrollview

So I can not use a static instance.

because The first item takes a callback.

How can I solve it?

Comment: `this.myCallbackFunc.bind(this)`? (I don't know typesript though)

Comment: Jaromanda X - thanks. Resolved.